# Define multiple distinct URIs in a Grails 2 web application filter

Tags: grails, filter

Is it possible to define multiple distinct URI's using Grails 2 web application filter?

For example, something like:

```
def filters = {
    someFilterMethod(uri: '/auth/**|/*/user/modify') {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[This is an open issue](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-3137) which is planned to be fixed in Grails 2.3 (according to the JIRA entry).

As a work-around you could extract the common code block to be used by multiple filter methods.